# Calldata and Payload for multiple calls

Tags: abiencoderv2

If I understand well, payload and calldata are the same thing ? Basically are the bytes representation of the function that is called. I heard this was useful for calling many functions in a single call.

Suppose I have a simple function I want to call multiple times

`function getReserves(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal view returns (uint reserveA, uint reserveB);`

My understanding is I can magically encode this function into a payload (or calldata?)
and then sending this to my contract which is going to call

```
function callPayloads(address target, bytes[] memory _payloads) external view returns (uint256[2][] memory) {

for (uint256 i = 0; i < _payloads.length; i++) {
      (bool _success, bytes memory _response) = targets.call(_payloads[i]); 
            require(_success); _response;                                              
      }

}
```

Can I use this instead of using multi-call aggregate calls or is there a difference? Also how can I encode the target contract address and function into payloads? using ethers or any other method
a

also does this payload needs to be signed by a private key?

Sorry If these come as a duplicate but most of the threads I have seen are too technical for me and would like a more basic explanation for dummy people :')

Answer (score 3):

Technically they are different things:

- **calldata** is a memory region where the contract's input is stored.
- **payload** is data that will be sent to another contract.

In simple terms, *calldata* is the container and *payload* is the content inside the container.